# mongoose statics method error: not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Mongoose static function for my model. But when I try to use the function it throws an error: `User.findbByCredintials is not a function`.

Here is the `User` model definition:

```js
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {..},
    age: {..},
    email: {..},
    password: {..}
});

userSchema.statics.findByCredintials = async function (email){
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if(!user) {
        return null;
    } else
        return user;
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
    User
}
```

And here I use it in my `userRouter`:

```js
const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredintials(req.body.email);
        if(!user){
            throw new Error('login failed');
        }
        
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
        if(!isMatch){
            throw new Error({error: 'login failed'});
        }

        res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're exporting an object, it should be `module.exports = User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export the User model, you're exporting an object:

```js
module.exports = { User }
```

You will either export the model like this:

```js
module.exports = User
```

**OR** import it like this:

```js
const { User } = require('../models/user');
```